# Как сделать сайт без перезагрузки на react.js?

Tags: javascript, apache, reactjs

Использую *react-router* и есть примерно вот такой код:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Contents}>
      <IndexRoute component={MainContent}/>
      <Route path=":id" component={MoreItemSite} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
  , document.getElementById('app')
);
```

На сервере все работает хорошо. Все рендериться без перезагрузки страницы. Но из `hashHistory` адрес получается некрасивым. Заменил `hashHistory` на `browserHistory` и прописал следующие в *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

С такими настройками переход по ссылкам и адрес выглядит нормально, страница при этом перезагружается. Как можно исправить эту проблему с использованием `browserHistory`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось лучше использовать конструкцию

```
<Link to="#"></Link>
```

Вместо обычных ссылок

```
<a href="#"></a>
```